# How to pass a Value from MVC Controller to Angular View

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using angularjs with Asp.net MVC to check the write access of a folder for users. If the user has the write access then I want to show a div which has a link. I have a div in `SampleView.Html` and I have a method which checks for user's write access in MVC Controller called `ReportController.cs`. What will be the code for Angular Controller that I can use to pass value from MVC controller to Angularjs View?

SampleView.html:

```
<div id="DivPackerTemplate" class="cp-btn cp-btn-primary pull-right">
<a ng-href="\\Samplefolder" >Edit Template</a></div>
```

ReportController.cs:

```
public void AccessPackerPlanTemplate(string folderPath)
        {          
            string path = @"\\sample";
                string NtAccountName = @"sampleuser";

                DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
                DirectorySecurity acl = di.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.All);
                AuthorizationRuleCollection rules = acl.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));

                //Go through the rules returned from the DirectorySecurity
                foreach (AuthorizationRule rule in rules)
                {
                    //If we find one that matches the identity we are looking for
                    if (rule.IdentityReference.Value.Equals(NtAccountName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        //Cast to a FileSystemAccessRule to check for access rights
                        if ((((FileSystemAccessRule)rule).FileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.WriteData) > 0)
                        {
                            //Show the link
                            {
                                DivPackerTemplate.Visible = false; \\This is not working is there a alternative for this?
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: use ng-show on the div

Comment: You need to send some sort of value to Angular controller in order to hide the div.  What data is displayed on the HTML page?  Is there any field that you could use as a bool for whether or not the div should be hidden?

Comment: @RaniRadcliff  HTML page is like a home page on which I dont want to show a link of a folder to everybody but only to specific users which have write access to the folder.I can convert this method from Void to bool.

Comment: Where are you calling the MVC Code in your Angular Controller? What is your Angular Controller receiving from MVC?  You can't control Angular directly from an MVC Controller.

Comment: @RaniRadcliff  I am fairly new to Angularjs and was curious to know how do I get values from MVC Controller and send it to Angular controller in this case?

Comment: Are your Angular App and Controller already created?  You will also need to create an Angular Service or Factory to make an $http call to your MVC Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might not be understanding the question exactly correctly, but I you case it might be best just to show or hide it using razor syntax, rather than exposing a variable and handling that in the JavaScript. If you're not returning a Model from your ASP.NET controller, then in your ASP.NET controller set the ViewBag variable like this:

```
ViewBag.DivPackerTemplateVisible = false;
```

And in your view:

```
@if(ViewBag.DivPackerTemplateVisible) {
    <div id="DivPackerTemplate" class="cp-btn cp-btn-primary pull-right"><a ng-href="\\Samplefolder" >Edit Template</a></div>

}
```

You should also make sure that ViewBag.DivPackerTemplateVisible always has a value of true or false, possibly by declaring it to true at the top of your ASP.NET controller.